# Globbing Pattern in the Beginning of file?

Tags: bash

How do I match globbing pattern in the beginning of the line?
For example I have a file containing the following

```
abcdef
abcXXf
XXcXXX
XXXXXf
aXcXXf
```

And I want to find lines that begin with X or have c in the third character.

However `gref {^x,^??c} somefile.doc` does not seem to work. Any ideas?

Comment: You're mixing up regular expressions ("regex", which `grep` uses to match file contents), glob patterns (which the shell uses to find lists of matching filenames), and brace expansions (which the shell uses as a shorthand for multiple items). In particular, you're trying to use a mix of brace expansion and glob patterns, when `grep` expects a regular expression. And BTW there are also multiple dialects of regex. You need to use the right pattern syntax for the tool and context that it'll be used in.

Comment: If your sample input had contained some lines that did NOT match the desired regexp and you had provided expected output then we'd have a [mcve] to test against. As it stands now someone could test a complete wrong regexp (e.g. `grep . file`) against your sample input and get the same output as with the right regexp so it's not a good test case.

Answer (score 1):

Try splitting into multiple patterns with multiple -e options.

```
grep -e ^x -e ^..c somefile.doc
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `|` to represent "alternates":

```
grep '^x\|^..c' somefile.doc
```

*edit:* Escaped `|`

Comment: ( and | are not special in grep; your pattern will tried to be matched literally.  Use your pattern with `egrep`, or with `grep -E`, or use `grep '^\(x\|..c\)' `.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ grep -E '^(X|.{2}c)' file
abcdef
abcXXf
XXcXXX
XXXXXf
aXcXXf
```